# Pubnub.subscribe not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am trying to implement a simple chat in my `AngularJs 1.4.5` web app using `pubnub`.

I am following the steps as given in the [pubnub tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/angularjs/chat-getting-started/#receiving-messages).

```
$scope.channel = 'chat_for_trial';
$scope.uuid = 'user1';

Pubnub.init({
    publishKey: 'demo',
    subscribeKey: 'demo',
    uuid: $scope.uuid
});

// Send the messages over PubNub Network
$scope.messageContent = {message: ''};

$scope.sendMessage = function() {
    // $scope.messageContent = data;
    // Don't send an empty message 
    if (!$scope.messageContent.message || $scope.messageContent.message === '') {
         return;
     }
     Pubnub.publish({
         channel: $scope.channel,
         message: {
             content: $scope.messageContent.message,
             sender_uuid: $scope.uuid,
             date: new Date()
         },
         callback: function(m) {
             console.log(m);
         }
     });
     // Reset the messageContent input
     $scope.messageContent.message = '';

 };

 //get messages
 $scope.messageContent.messages = [];

// Subscribing to the ‘messages-channel’ and trigering the message callback
Pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: $scope.channel,
    triggerEvents: ['callback']
});

// Listening to the callbacks
$scope.$on(Pubnub.getMessageEventNameFor($scope.channel), function (ngEvent, m) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        console.log("i am here")
        $scope.messageContent.messages.push(m)
    });
});
```

I can send message to the channel `chat_for_trial` but when checking the occupancy in [pubnub console](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/console), the subscribed `uuid` is not listed.

When I sending the message from console it is not displayed in the web app. But data sent from web app can be seen in the pubnub console.

I am working with `pubnub: 4.20.1`, `pubnub-angular: 4.1.0`, `angularjs: 1.4.5`

I would like to know what I am missing here.

Comment: What is the exact content of the message you are sending from the dev console vs the message from your app? Can another client using your web app receive a message sent from the other client using your web app? Are you able to see the message in the Browser Network tab (subscribe call returns with the message)? Are you sure `$scope.channel` in your `subscribe` is the same channel name that you are publishing to?

Comment: Also you should consider [PubNub ChatEngine](https://github.com/pubnub/chat-engine#angular) to build your chat app.

Comment: @CraigConover No the message sent from one client is not visible in the network tab of the other client. Yes `$scope.channel` is a fixed value only the user id varies based on the logged in user.

Comment: OK, so if you are not even receiving the message "behind the scenes" of your app, then your app is not actually subscribed to the channel. Could be a variable scope issue where PubNub or the addListener code is going out of scope. I would suggest debugging into that. If you require further assistance from PubNub, please file a ticket with PubNub support (include your sub-key, error messages if any, attach code files, etc) and reference this SO thread/link so we can post back any valuable answers for the public.

Comment: @CraigConover Thank you for your support. I found that the issue was due to the mismatch of the `sdk` version in the tutorial and my installed sdk version. The tutorial is for `sdk v3` but the current available version is `sdk v4`. I have updated my question with what my error was and how it was fixed.

Comment: I should have known that looking at your code but I missed it. Your init code is v4 but your publish/subscribe code is v3 style. Glad you figured it out. You should post your last comment at the official answer, you get extra points for that, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the mismatch of the `pubnub and pubnub-angular` version from the tutorial and the one installed using `bower` in my application.

The tutorial was for `sdk v3` and the current sdk version `v4`.

Refer [this link](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-angular) for working with pubnub sdk v4.